# ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut.class

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have an error after i try to build the apk using Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/BaseFragmentActivityDonut.class

I have no clue on how i can solve this, any help would be very appreciated!!

Comment: You should show your Gradle file and remove all your JAR files from the libs folder, if you have any

Comment: What version of Gradle and Android Gradle plugin are you using? What dependencies does your project have?

Comment: @cricket_007 I removed all of my files from libs folder and it's works, you must knowed that i switched from Eclipse :) !! Thank you!!

Comment: Yeah, Eclipse including the support jar libraries has been an issue for awhile